# Selecting records with maximum value in group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a transaction table with the following structure:

```
select t.[GUID], t.[ID], ts.Description "Status", t.Payee, t.Amount, t.SequenceNumber
  from [Transaction] t
 inner join TransactionStatus ts on t.StatusID = ts.ID

GUID                                 | ID | Status  | Payee | Amount | SequenceNumber
AF732CF5-E6C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2 | 1  | Posted  | Amy   | 500.00 | 1
AF732CF5-E6C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2 | 2  | Voided  | Amy   | 500.00 | 2
1F7D880C-E7C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2 | 3  | Posted  | Bob   |  70.00 | 1
AF732CF5-E6C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2 | 4  | Posted  | Amy   | 512.50 | 3
1F7D880C-E7C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2 | 5  | Posted  | Bob   |  66.00 | 2
F2CC0B03-76C7-E411-A48D-004056AB787C | 6  | Pending | Carol | 240.00 | NULL
```

I'm trying to construct a query to group the records by GUID and select the single record with the largest SequenceNumber (if it isn't NULL):

```
GUID                                 | ID | Status  | Payee | Amount | SequenceNumber
AF732CF5-E6C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2 | 4  | Posted  | Amy   | 512.50 | 3
1F7D880C-E7C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2 | 5  | Posted  | Bob   | 66.00  | 2
F2CC0B03-76C7-E411-A48D-004056AB787C | 6  | Pending | Carol | 240.00 | NULL
```

I've tried adding this line:

```
where SequenceNumber = (select MAX(SequenceNumber) from [Transaction] t2 where t.[GUID] = t2.[GUID])
```

but that doesn't get me any transactions where the status is Pending (they don't have sequence numbers). How can I fix this query?

Comment: @TimSchmelter SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's SQL-Server you can use a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) + [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    select t.[GUID], t.[ID], ts.Description "Status", t.Payee, t.Amount, t.SequenceNumber,
           rn = row_number() over (partition by  t.[GUID] Order By t.SequenceNumber DESC)
    from [Transaction] t
    inner join TransactionStatus ts on t.StatusID = ts.ID
)
SELECT GUID, ID, Status, Payee, Amount, SequenceNumber
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

This will include the row where `SequenceNumber` is null. If you want all rows with the maximum  `SequenceNumber`(in case of ties) use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the `MAX(ID)` and it's related `[GUID]` in a subquery and `JOIN` to it in order to get the desired results:

**Sample subquery:**

```
SELECT  [GUID] ,
        MAX(ID) MaxId
FROM    Transaction
GROUP BY [GUID]
```

Would produce:

```
GUID                                    MaxId
1F7D880C-E7C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2    5
AF732CF5-E6C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2    4
F2CC0B03-76C7-E411-A48D-004056AB787C    6
```

**Full Demo:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Transaction
    (
      [GUID] VARCHAR(36) ,
      [ID] INT ,
      [Status] VARCHAR(7) ,
      [Payee] VARCHAR(5) ,
      [Amount] INT ,
      [SequenceNumber] VARCHAR(4)
    );

INSERT  INTO #Transaction
        ( [GUID], [ID], [Status], [Payee], [Amount], [SequenceNumber] )
VALUES  ( 'AF732CF5-E6C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2', 1, 'Posted', 'Amy', 500.00,
          '1' ),
        ( 'AF732CF5-E6C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2', 2, 'Voided', 'Amy', 500.00,
          '2' ),
        ( '1F7D880C-E7C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2', 3, 'Posted', 'Bob', 70.00,
          '1' ),
        ( 'AF732CF5-E6C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2', 4, 'Posted', 'Amy', 512.50,
          '3' ),
        ( '1F7D880C-E7C0-E411-B8F6-004056AB77C2', 5, 'Posted', 'Bob', 66.00,
          '2' ),
        ( 'F2CC0B03-76C7-E411-A48D-004056AB787C', 6, 'Pending', 'Carol',
          240.00, NULL );

SELECT  #Transaction.*
FROM    #Transaction
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT [GUID] ,
                            MAX(ID) MaxId
                     FROM   #Transaction
                     GROUP BY [GUID]
                   ) t ON t.[GUID] = #Transaction.[GUID]
                          AND t.MaxId = #Transaction.ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to get maximum `SequenceNumber`

```
CASE WHEN MAX(SequenceNumber IS NULL) = 0 THEN MAX(SequenceNumber) ELSE NULL END AS SequenceNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if SQL Server has windowing functions, so you may be able to do this more cleanly, but here's a vanilla SQL solution:

```
select    highest.[GUID],
          highest.[ID],
          ts.Description "Status",
          highest.Payee,
          highest.Amount,
          highest.SequenceNumber
from      [Transaction] highest
join      TransactionStatus ts
on        ts.ID                 = highest.ID
left join [Transaction] higher
on        higher.[GUID]         = highest.[GUID]
and       higher.SequenceNumber > highest.SequenceNumber
where     higher.[GUID]        is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

omething like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  select 
        t.[GUID], t.[ID], ts.Description "Status", t.Payee, t.Amount, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION BY (t.[GUID]
    ORDER BY t.SequenceNumber DESC) AS rownum
              from [Transaction] t
             inner join TransactionStatus ts on t.StatusID = ts.ID
)vals where vals.rownum = 1
```